# Como paginar os dados? Via StoredProcedure ou DataView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, jquery-datatables, datatable

Estou utilizando o DataTables.net com server-side via WebForm e Ado.net.

Preciso paginar os dados (ordernar, filtrar, etc), vejo 2 possibilidades:

```
- via stored procedure
ou
- via DataView
```

O Problema é que ao utilizar DataTables.net ele me envia 62 campos pela Querystring no qual terei que tratar e montar as possíveis páginações, acredito que via StoredProcedure será um monstro fazer isso.

Normalmente a quantidade de registros variam entre 400 a 3mil.

OBS: Não é muito viável eu colocar o Entity Framework somente para solucionar esse problema.

**O que recomendam? Estou propenço a começar a desenvolver em DataView com RowFilter, Sort, etc.**

OBS²: Hoje o DataTables chama um Generic Handler no qual faço as consultas no banco de dados e retorno o resultado via JSON

Comment: É viável sim colocar o Entity Framework. É só o modo de fazer que exige algum cuidado. Você pode colocar um pouco de código na sua pergunta?

Comment: A dúvida acho que é mais teórica, não vejo qual código devo colocar, pensei em fazer via DataView e podendo fazer o filtro via Linq ou direto no DataView.

Comment: Bom, opinativamente falando, eu diria que é melhor você sair do WebForms, então o caminho seria usando DataTables + Ajax, mas isso vai dar algum trabalho.

Comment: é esse meu sistema precisa ser 'atualizado' porém ele é gigante em webform, da até um desespero pensar em migra-lo...rs faz freela Cigano?

Comment: Faço. [Entra aqui pra gente conversar](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25342/c-asp-net-asp-net-mvc-entity-framework-etc).